# Do we need to use DynamoDB LastEvaluatedKey when querying GSI using KeyConditionExpression where partitionKey value is unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB. I have a table which has GSI (Global Secondary Index). GSI partitionKey values are unique.

I want to use query operation to get items using GSI partitionKey. Usually when you use query operation you need to use LastEvaluatedKey to get all the results. In my case I know that there should be 1 or 0 results.

Do I need to make multiple query requests using LastEvaluatedKey to get this item or one request should be enough?

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect the answer is "no", but that's not authoritative. When you invoke query with the GSI pk, I would assume that DynamoDB makes use of the GSI to go directly to the first item that has that pk. It's not going to have to do any filtering, so I would not expect to have to be concerned with LastEvaluatedKey given that you know there will be at most one matching item.

Comment: Yeah, the problem here is that the answer depends on the implementation. I could't find it in the documentation.

Comment: The answer by SHenghow95 is correct, but as a bit of help for an example - LastEvaluatedKey is for document Pagination. You can think of a dynamodb query as returning only the first X items on the first page - (up to the memory limits of a query per AWS) and if you want to view the next set of items, you "move to the next page" by querying with LastEvaluatedKey value to "turn" the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be 100% guaranteed that you'll never get a `LastEvaluatedKey` in response to a `Query` returning 0 or 1 items? No.

Fun fact: `Query` calls won't cross partition boundaries. Should a boundary be hit you'll see a `LastEvaluatedKey` and have to do a second request to read into the next partition.

Now, this is an implementation detail subject to change. The API contract you're given with the `Query` call is to expect that an `LEK` might be returned and be prepared to do a second call as required. Deciding "Nah I don't think I'll need to" is a risky move. Even if you're safe today, will you be safe tomorrow? When the docs don't promise you a behavior, best not to rely too much on it.

OK, so you know you should, and you probably knew that before. What you really want to know is if not "wearing a helmet" here will ever "conk you on the head". Can we invent a scenario where DynamoDB won't know reliably in advance into what partition to start processing a Query to find the 0 or 1 items to return?

Imagine that over time an item collection has been split across partitions, and items have been added and removed. There will be a set of partitions, more than one partition might cover the same PK value, and each will cover some subset of the SK values.

```
Partition A: PK = "x", SK=[1 to 10]
Partition B: PK = "x", SK=[11 to max]
```

Then imagine you do a `Query` where `PK = "x" and SK > 9` limiting results to 1. Will that item be in Partition A or Partition B? Well, we don't know for sure. DynamoDB will have to start at Partition A but might not find any items and need to continue with B. You'll see `LastEvaluatedKey`.

Conk!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to include LastEvaluatedKey in your **FIRST** DynamoDB `Query`.

However, it is still recommended that you performs a checking if the results has value for `LastEvaluatedKey`, then only you proceed to perform the next DynamoDB `Query` with `ExclusiveStartKey` equals to your `LastEvaluatedKey`.

An example in `python`:

```
results = []

response = DDB_TABLE.query(
    IndexName='gsi-status',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('status').eq('COMPLETED')
)

if response.get('Items'):
    results.extend(response.get('Items'))

while response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
    response = DDB_TABLE.query(
        IndexName='gsi-status',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('status').eq('COMPLETED')
    )

    if response.get('Items'):
        results.extend(response.get('Items'))
```

Comment: The OP already knows how to use LastEvaluatedKey. That's not the issue. It's whether or not it's even relevant in this specific scenario.

Comment: the answer said that: `There is no need for you to include LastEvaluatedKey in your FIRST DynamoDB Query` - if the poster knows there will only be one item and it can always be returned by a single query, then by default this is their first query, and so does not need LastEvaluated.

Comment: @lynkfox the OP knows this. That's not the question, at least as I understand it.